# Animate expanding table row

Tags: angularjs, animation

I have a calendar represented with a table.  The content of each day may be too much to display so the height is fixed and the overflow hidden.  However when the user hovers over the row I have the entire row expand.  This is working perfectly.  What I need to ease the *transition* of the divs in the row from height:60px to height:auto, perhaps slow it to about 500ms.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2, I have ngAnimate loaded as well as animate.css (used elsewhere in the app).

Each day in the calendar is a div within a td tag.

```
div.cal_container
{
  height:60px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

And when I hover over the row this is what I use to expand the whole row:

```
table.cal tr:hover > td > div
{
  height:auto;
}
```

How do I animate the height transition?

Comment: Are your rows in an ngRepeat? What have you tried so far? Do you want to use CSS transitions with ngAnimate?

Comment: Yes there are ngRepeats for both the rows (weeks) and the columns (days), like this: <tr ng-repeat="week in weeks"> <td ng-repeat="day in days">.  Transitions are fine if they work.

Comment: Forgot to add that I tried adding "transition: height 0.5s;" to both the CSS sections shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that transitions don't like height:auto.  I found this solution/workaround and it's giving me 95% of what I wanted:

Add max height to the div:

```
div.cal_container
{
  height:60px; 
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height: 60px;
}
```

Add the transition to the *max-height* in the row selector CSS:

```
table.cal tr:hover > td > div
{
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height 0.75s ease-in;
  height:auto;  
}
```

The last bit I'd like to get is to ease the transition back to height:60px when they stop hovering but this is less important.